# java class.forName(String)

Tags: java, class, declaration

I have no idea how to deal with the error which is occurring after compiling this program.

```
public class Kolumna {

    private String nazwa;
    private String typ;
    public ArrayList<?> kolumna;

    public Kolumna(String _nazwa, String _typ) {
        nazwa = _nazwa;
        typ = _typ;
        Class class_def;
        try {
            class_def = Class.forName(typ);
            kolumna = new ArrayList<class_def>();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Nie ma takiego typu!");
        }
    }
}
```

The error says:

> "dataFrame/Kolumna.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
>               kolumna = new ArrayList();"

I tried to move class_def declaration around but it's not helping

Comment: Use a method within your class.

Comment: You forgot to declare the variable `kolumna`

Comment: `kolumna` lacks of type declaration

Comment: `new ArrayList<class_def>` is invalid. You can't use a variable as the type parameter like that. If you're loading the class at runtime, you'll have to use a raw type or `<Object>` (or `<SomeInterface>` if the loaded class is known to conform to a given interface).

Comment: no declaration of kolumna

Answer (score 1):

Generics are a compile time check. You can define the constructor like this.

```
public final List kolumna = new ArrayList(); // nothing to check at compile time

public Kolumna(String _nazwa, String _typ) {
    nazwa = _nazwa;
    typ = _typ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
  class Kolumna {
       private String nazwa;
       private String typ;
       public ArrayList kolumna = new ArrayList();
       public Kolumna(String _nazwa, String _typ) {
            nazwa = _nazwa;
            typ = _typ;
            Class class_def;
            try {
               class_def = Class.forName(typ);
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Nie ma takiego typu!");
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: But I need to create ArrayList of the type given in arguments :(